# why value can not be set in mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a beginner to mapreduce. I want my reduce process like: 
given a set of input of same key like (key1, 100), (key1, #50), (key1, #25), I want to output (key1, 50/100), (key1, 25/100). That is the value of the one with '#' divided by the value of the one without '#'.

Because I think the location with (key1,100) may be unknown after map process. So I iterate through the whole set to get the (key1, 100) and store #50,#25 into a list. Then iterate through the list to calculate 50/100, 25/100. Is that any OK? Here is my code:

```
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
        private Text reskey = new Text();
        private Text resvalue = new Text();
        private List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                           Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            try {
                String prefix = new String(key.toString());

                int total = 0;
                for (Text val : values) {
                    String value = new String(val.toString());
                    if (!value.contains("#")) {
                        total = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    }else{
                        arr.add(value);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; ++i) {
                    String value = arr.get(i);
                    if (value.contains("#")) {
                        String[] words = value.split("#");
                        int number = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        double probability = 1.0 * number / total;
                        reskey.set(prefix);
                        resvalue.set(Double.toString(probability));
                        context.write(reskey, resvalue);
                    }
                }
                arr.clear();
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that the variable 'total' in the second for loop always remains 0. I think is should be assigned in the first for loop because when I print it in the first for loop it is not 0. But in the second for loop it becomes 0(the initial value). What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry something doesn't show correctly in second paragraph.  I want my reduce function solve the problem: Given a set of input of same key like <key1, 100>,<key1, #50> , <key1, #25>, I want to output <key1, 50/100>, <key1, 25/100>.

Comment: Did you check log? probably you have runtime exception in your code, but you cant see it because of try/catch, try to remove it and see. Also I think you have bug: you don't erase you array at the start of reduce function.

Comment: I set the combiner to be the same as reducer. Sorry for that.